# In transferring a family cemetery layout to a digital format, I need a software program

Tags: open-source-gis, software-recommendations, digitizing

We have a large historic family cemetery. I've had surveying experience, drafting in the days when it was done by hand, and a lot of real estate experience with deed descriptions and layouts on maps. What I don't have is experience with this in the CAD digital world although I use the computer daily for other work. We want to transfer the information from our paper layout (some 2 acres with 300+ burial sites as well as additional information) to one that's digital to make it easier to make changes. There are many programs out there for commercial use - expensive - and many that are free or inexpensive. Can somone provide any advice on which of the latter to choose?

Comment: For a GIS option consider Manifold.net, qgis is good but no where near as slick for digitizing

Answer (score 2):

A free tool that will help you explore what you can do within GIS, is [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/). It will most likely be a little tricky to digitize and import the information but you can start with loading a basemap (say Openstreetmap) and trace out the boundary of your property.

Then, you can try to import some scans of your paper copies and geo-rectify them. This just means clicking on a point on the scan and clicking on one on the real-world map (see the Geo-Referencer tool in QGIS). You can then skew the scan to the real world and start tracing out the plot outlines.

Finally, you probably want to understand how the polygon is related to other information. Attributes can be associated with a polygon (like owner, etc) and when you click on a polygon you can enter this information in.

Hope that helps, and happy to answer any followup questions.

Answer (score 2):

If you do choose to use a CAD, rather than GIS program for your needs, There are also open-source CAD programs like [QCAD](http://www.qcad.org/en/).

Answer (score 2):

**There are a large number of FOSS options that would be suitable for a project like this.** I am going to end up recommending that you use [QGIS](http://qgis.org/en/site/). I will address the question in three parts:

1. Non-GIS options.
2. GIS options, and why I recommend QGIS.
3. Some pointers to QGIS tutorials.

## Non-GIS options

Since you have come to a GIS-focused site, you are indicating that you are leaning towards a GIS solution, and you will tend to get GIS-based answers. But the first thing to point out is that, if you do not *need* your cemetery plots to be referenced to an earth location, you do not *need* to use GIS, much the way that someone would do interior design using a general drawing or architectural software, since you don't need to know the lat-long of the floor lamp.

Your non-GIS options are primarily to use a generic drawing program, or to use a CAD program. For this kind of project, using a straightforward drawing program would be perfectly acceptable, and if you happen to already have experience with graphic design software, could be a very low-difficulty solution. Since your data (property bounds, burial sites) are primarily vector (points, lines and polygons), you would probably want to use [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/), and open source alternative to Adobe Illustrator. If you are already familiar with a raster image software like Adobe Photoshop, you might check out [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/).

If your eventual goal is publishable output, it's worth mentioning that many cartographers export their work from GIS to graphic design software for the final touches, so for a one-shot project, it might not be a bad choice to just use graphic design software for the whole thing.

If you want more precision and are already familiar with CAD, open source alternatives to commercial CAD packages include [LibreCAD](http://librecad.org/cms/home.html) and [QCAD](http://www.qcad.org/en/).

Since this is not the focus of your question or this site (and since I have limited experience with these softwares), I won't elaborate, but this *is* a viable option, especially if you already have some experience with CAD or graphic design. GIS is really only necessary if your data need to be geographically referenced. Your house and yard exists somewhere on the earth, but most architects and designers do *not* use GIS for home/landscape design, because all that matters for them is an arbitrary local coordinate system, i.e., how far things are from each other in their area of interest, rather than how far things are from other, properties, roads, physical features, political boundaries, etc.

## GIS options, and why I recommend QGIS

If you want to use GIS, there are many open source options. Major open source desktop GIS software include [QGIS](http://qgis.org/en/site/), [uDig](http://udig.refractions.net/), [gvSIG](http://www.gvsig.com/en), [OpenJUMP](http://www.openjump.org/), and probably quite a few others. Another major player is [GRASS](https://grass.osgeo.org/), but it is primarily oriented towards raster manipulation and analysis, and has a steeper learning curve than these other options, so I think it is not what you would want.

I have a lot of experience with QGIS. Frankly, I have minimal experience with uDig and no experience with gvSIG or OpenJUMP. Without disparaging anyone who is a committed user of these other softwares, I have gravitated to QGIS because I have found it to be the most user-friendly, and because it has an *extremely* active and helpful user community. It is worth noting that the [qgis](/questions/tagged/qgis) tag is not just the top tag for a desktop GIS but is *the* top tag on this site. Although it is hard to get statistics on open source software use (I invite edits here), I think that this is reflective of QGIS's popularity in the FOSS4G community.

What this means for you is that if you start using QGIS you will find a large number of high quality tutorials, and support questions on this site will tend to produce a large number of high quality responses.

## Pointers to QGIS tutorials

Because your main question is "What software is there?", I will offer just a few points if you decide you want to go the route. Post additional questions once you get going.

1. I have described QGIS installation and have links to general tutorials on my blog at http://geospatial.commons.gc.cuny.edu/getting-oriented-to-qgis/.
2. Since you already have paper maps, in order to get the scanned images into the QGIS, you can follow this tutorial: [Georeferencing Topo Sheets and Scanned Maps](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html).
3. The most important step is doing the georeferencing is choosing an appropriate local coordinate system for your data. This is a large enough question to need to be addressed separately, but you can take guidance from (a) the reference system used by your original maps *if* they have one, and (b) the reference system used by your local government for parcel records.

Good luck, and welcome to the world of GIS!

Comment: Thanks for all the information. It has helped me solve the problem and which way to go for the software.